# Multiple versions of the same question?

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers

Let's say I asked an unclear question, people in the comments said that the question is unclear and they talked about the unclear contents in my question, I edited the question making it clear and tidy, but the comments are still there that have arguments about clarifying the question, if a new viewer comes and see the question for the first time he wouldn't understand the comments correctly because these comments were commented on the old version of the post.

Sometimes I myself when editing a question I try as hard as possible to link the question with the comments so if people read the question and the comments they understand that I have made an edit based on the comments.

My suggestion is that when anybody comment or answer their answer or comment get a small indicator indicating at which version was this comment or answer posted to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Just so you don't get discouraged, downvotes on meta just mean "nah, I don't think we should have that", rather than "your question is stupid"

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Ok I understand it.

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. I didn't even spot the mistagging ;) This is a feature request

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica oh yeah sorry, I am new here ...

Comment: @Shams That's ok it's solved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> but the comments are still there that have arguments about clarifying the question

Then you flag your own question for moderator attention and ask the moderator(s) to cleanup all the no longer required comments. Alternatively, you can click on each comment that you think is no longer necessary ... and directly flag that comment as "no longer needed".

But as said: in case there are multiple comments that better be gone, it is perfectly fair to ask moderation to look into helping with cleanup all at once, instead of doing that manually for 5 or 10 comments.

Finally, you can also simply notify each author with a comment like "thanks for your input, I adapted my question, please consider removing your comment" or something like that. I do that almost every time I get a constructive comment on a question or answer. Then you only need to bother the moderators when the comment authors don't come back by themselves.